# Display dc.js to leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using cross filter, dc.js and leaflet to display data on an interactive dashboard.

This is my code for grouping and showing me the data table which is working fine.

```
.group(function (d) {
        var format = d3.format('02d');
        return d.Timestamp.getFullYear() + '/' + format((d.Timestamp.getMonth() + 1));
    })
            .columns([
                "Timestamp",
                "KMIST_TEMP_ID",
                "ID POP",
                "CUSTOMER NAME",
                "district",
                "ward",
                ]);
```

I want to return on a map with leaflet my geographic coordinates which are in the data table.

```
pharmaciesMarkers.clearLayers();
                _.each(format.top(Infinity), function (d) {
                  var name = d.CUSTOMER NAME;
                  var marker = L.marker([loc.lat, loc.long]);
                  pharmaciesMarkers.addLayer(marker);
                  marker.bindPopup("<p>" + CUSTOMER NAME + " " + loc.KMIST_TEMP_ID + " " + loc.ward + "</p>");
                });
                map.addLayer(pharmaciesMarkers);
                map.fitBounds(pharmaciesMarkers.getBounds())
```

What am I doing wrong here, why the markers do not display on the map?

Comment: I'd prefer you describe the problem than me assuming what the problem is.

Comment: @choz cannot display the geographic coordinates on the map

Comment: I think we'd need more code (or preferably a reproducible example like a bl.ock or jsFiddle) in order to help you diagnose this. For example, you don't show the definition of `format` or `loc`. Are you getting any errors in the browser console which might help point the way? Also note that there is [dc.leaflet.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js) which may make this a little easier, since it already has the binding between dc.js and markers on a leaflet map.

Comment: @Gordon 
 Uncaught dc.errors.InvalidStateException ; Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at (index):266
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.js:1996)
    at Object.event (d3.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.js:1949)

Comment: Answered [on the users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/_AT7cYOo5mI/QoLV_BLiCwAJ).